# How to add number masking on input text field in adf 12c

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to add validation on input text field in adf 12c .jsf page.
When user is entering CNIC it should be in "xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x" this format, otherwise it will show error to input in correct format.
Here is my input field code:

```
<af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.Name.inputValue}" 
    label="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.label}" 
    required="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.mandatory}" 
    columns="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.displayWidth}"
    maximumLength="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.precision}"
    shortDesc="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.tooltip}" id="it2">
 <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.Name.validator}"/>
</af:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so is to use the validateRegex tag (https://www.javatpoint.com/jsf-validateregex).

It is used to check whether the local value of a component is a match against a regular expression from the java.util.regex package or not.

In your case :

```
<af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.Name.inputValue}" 
    label="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.label}" 
    required="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.mandatory}" 
    columns="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.displayWidth}"
    maximumLength="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.precision}"
    shortDesc="#{bindings.TblCertificationView1.hints.Name.tooltip}" id="it2">
 <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.Name.validator}"/>
 <f:validateRegex pattern="(^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]$)"/>
</af:inputText>
```